# Ionic- Cordova Build Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to run ionic I get the below error, Am I just missing cordova? or is it something else?

```
Usr:example1 user$ ionic add platform ios
Bower component installed - platform
Usr:example1 user$ ionic build ios
The provided path "/Users/user/ionicApps/example1/platforms/ios" is not a Cordova iOS project.
Usr:example1 user$
```

Cordova is actually installed, when I did cordova -v  I see 5.0.0

Comment: Are you running the command on MAC?? because you can add the ios platform in windows. However, building the ios project or emulating the ios project would require you to have the MAC and not windows.

Answer (score 6):

The command to add the iOS platform is:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

Make sure you're on a Mac because you can't do this on Windows or Linux.